# Redirect back to login page after session timeout ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-core-mvc

I would like to automatically redirect control to my Login page after session timeout.

So far i have added

```
services.AddCaching();
    services.AddSession(options => {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.CookieName = ".AIM";
    });
```

to my `startup.cs` file.

Anybody please let me know how to automatically be transferred to Login page after session timeout instead of clicking any button or link. I am currently using MVC6 ASP.NET5

Answer (score 4):

If you are talking about "authentication session" (basically an authentication cookie), then once it (cookie) expires you will be automatically redirected to Login page next time you try to access any page that is marked with [AuthorizeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx).

If you are talking about regular session you can write some JavaScript that will do an AJAX polling to determine whether the session is alive

Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult IsSessionAlive()
{ 
    if (Session.Contents.Count == 0)
    {
        return this.Json(new{ IsAlive = false}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
    }
    return this.Json(new{ IsAlive = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
}
```

client side JavaScript

```
function IsSessionAlive(){
  $.post( "SomeController/IsSessionAlive", function( data ) {
    if(!data.IsAlive)
    { 
        //If you may need to logout current user first than:
        $.post( '@Url.Action("LogOut","Account")', function( data ) {
             window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Login","Account")';
        });

        //if you don't need the logout:
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Login","Account")';
    }
  });
}

$(function(){
     //set interval to 5 minutes
     window.setInterval(IsSessionAlive, 300000);
})
```

Comment: Sorry to reply existing thread.


Instead of client-side polling, would it be possible for SignalR to push message client to trigger logout?

Comment: Sure, SignalR only provides an abstraction for client-server communication. It uses either web sockets if browser/server supports it and polling (long/short) if not.

Comment: Where should the client side javascript code be placed?